# Python: Transformar una lista en una lista de lista

Tags: python

En este código yo cambio los números strings de la **Lista** por enteros, y llego hasta aca (si corren mi código):

Lista1=['queso', 'pan', 12, 11, 'mirar', 'pelea', 12, 'amor', 30, 'ahi', 'no', 'nose', 'no', 'no', 34, 11, 7, 8, 9, 10]

Ahora necesito esa **lista1** volverla una lista de listas:

Lista1=[['queso', 'pan', 12, 11], ['mirar', 'pelea', 12, 'amor'], [30, 'ahi', 'no', 'nose', 'no', 'no', 34], [11, 7, 8, 9, 10]]

Cómo lo hago, agradezco la ayuda para finalizar el código.

````
lista=[['queso','pan','12','11'],
       ['mirar','pelea','12','amor'],
       ['30','ahi','no','nose','no','no','34'],
       ['11','7','8','9','10']
      ]

lista1=[]


for i in range(len(lista)):
    for j in range(len(lista[i])):
        try:
            ival=int(lista[i][j])
        except:
            ival=-1     
        if ival>0:
            lista1.append(ival) 
        else:
            lista1.append(lista[i][j])

print(lista1)```
````

Comment: ¿Por qué quieres que lista1 sea una lista de listas si `lista` ya es una lista de listas? ¿Qué es lo que quieres lograr?

Comment: Publicar multiples veces la misma pregunta es considerado `spam` ¿Qué hacemos con [esta otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/554226/171630) pregunta?

Comment: Hola Heytale ya elimine la otra pregunta, mi intención no era generar duplicidad, pense que publicando solo la inquietud era suficiente. Asi que disculplas. Soy nueva en stack.

Comment: Hola Jacobo, gracias por cuestionarme, me estaba enredando de más, ya arregle mi código. Que pases un buen día :)

Answer (score 1):

Viendo las dos preguntas que has hecho en conjunto ([aquí la otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/554226/python-convertir-una-lista-en-una-lista-de-listas-con-tama%C3%B1os-de-lista-diferent)) creo que el problema lo tienes en el origen de tu planteamiento, ya que estás haciendo pasos innecesarios.

En origen partes de esta lista de listas:

```
lista = [
    ['queso', 'pan', '12', '11'],
    ['mirar', 'pelea', '12', 'amor'],
    ['30', 'ahi', 'no', 'nose', 'no', 'no', '34'],
    ['11', '7', '8', '9', '10']
]
```

Lo que intuyo que tratas de hacer es convertir los strings con datos numéricos a tipo `int` pero manteniendo la estructura de la variable `lista`.

Tu planteamiento es convertir esa lista de listas a una lista de una única dimensión, cambiar los tipos de datos y volver a construir la lista de listas...

...cuando no hace falta hacer nada de eso.

### Solución explicada

```
for i, v in enumerate(lista):
    for j, w in enumerate(v):
        if w.isnumeric():
            lista[i][j] = int(w)
```

Esta es una solución bastante legible. Primero enumeramos lista para sacar de cada una de las listas anidadas el índice `i` y el contenido `v`.

A continuación enumeramos el contenido `v` para sacar de cada uno de los valores de esa lista anidada su índice `j` y su contenido `w`.

Comprobamos si `w` es numérico con `w.isnumeric()` y en caso afirmativo accedemos a la variable `lista` con los dos índices recuperados `lista[i][j]` y sustituimos el valor por la conversión a entero.

### Solución con list comprehension

```
lista = [[int(_) if _.isnumeric() else _ for _ in v] for v in lista]
```

Exactamente lo mismo pero utilizando list comprehension

### Solución con map

```
lista = map(lambda linea: [int(_) if _.isnumeric() else _ for _ in linea], lista)
```

Lo mismo que con list comprehension pero hay gente que lo ve así más claro

### Solución con recurrencia

```
def convert(ll):
    return [convert(_) if isinstance(_, list) else int(_) if _.isnumeric() else _ for _ in ll]

lista = convert(lista)
```

Con esta alternativa no estamos limitados a una lista de listas y podemos trabajar con más niveles de anidación, como por ejemplo:

```
lista = [
    ['queso', 'pan', '12', '11'],
    ['mirar', 'pelea', '12', 'amor'],
    ['30', 'ahi', 'no', 'nose', 'no', 'no', '34'],
    ['11', '7', '8', ['3', 'test', '12', ['otro test', '77']], '10']
]
```

## Nota

Obviamente esto está hecho sin tener en cuenta construcciones diferentes de la variable `lista`, por lo que se producirían excepciones en casos no controlados.

Comment: Gracias César, muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de explicarme. No tengo mucha experiencia programando en Python pero espero seguir mejorando con la comunidad Stack.